# Changing Exhaust on Royal Enfield

Tags: motorcycle, exhaust, enfield-bullet, royal-enfield

I want to change bend pipe and exhaust on my Royal Enfield Electra 5 speed 350 CC bike, it has old engine (NOT UCE). To my knowledge there are too many options like. Free flow mufflers, short bottle mufflers, megaphone etc. But I am nit very sure which one will produce the Royal Enfield sound and will have no effect on engine.

Please suggest